# CakePHP Login Username/Password Validation

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have the below in my users_controller because there is further logic needed to perform the login, however when done in CakePHP the default validation stops and therefore i am trying to force it to validate the username and password fields before doing the account check. Everything works fine but this. I have tried adding two if statements (below) to check if username/password is empty, however as soon as the page loads they are empty and the validation box shows.

I am stumped as to how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'shows'));
    }
    if(empty($this->data['User']['username'])) {
        $this->User->validationErrors['username'] = "Please enter a username";
    }
    if(empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->User->validationErrors['password'] = "Please enter a password";
    }
    if(!empty($this->data['User']['username'])) {
        // unset unrequired validation rules
        unset($this->User->validate['username']['unique']);

        // validate form
        $this->User->set($this->data);
        if($this->User->validates()) {
            // update Last Login date
            $this->User->id = $this->User->_user['User']['id'];
            $this->User->saveField('last_login',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

            // save User to Session and redirect
            $this->Session->write('User', $this->User->_user);
            $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged in.','default',array('class'=>'flash_green'));
            //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'shows', 'admin'=>FALSE));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect username/password combination.','default',array('class'=>'flash_red'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login', 'admin'=>FALSE));
        }
    }
}
```

users_controller beforeFilter()

```
    function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('register');
}
```

app_controller beforeFilter and components

```
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false),
    //'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'shows', 'action'=>'index'),
    'autoRedirect' => false,
    'authorize' => 'controller')
);

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('home');
    $this->set('admin', $this->_isAdmin());
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->_loggedIn());
    $this->set('users_username', $this->_usersUsername());
}
```

Comment: i think i figured it out, at the end of the login function i had it redirecting back to the login action therefore resetting the validation. '$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login', 'admin'=>FALSE));'. Just have a weird issue with the password skipping the empty validation and warning about length instead...

Comment: fixed this too with 'last'=>true in the model validation. It is the way cakephp iterates over each rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below code from the user_controller.php file.

```
 else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect username/password combination.','default',array('class'=>'flash_red'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login', 'admin'=>FALSE));
    }
```

This is looping the page back to the login action with no data and therefore no validation.

Answer (score 0):

If your "default validation" stops then something is wrong there. If you have something in your before filters in the model make sure they return true. I suggest you to write a unit test for that.

You definitely do not have to do the !empty checks in the controller. The whole codeblock could be reduced to ~6 lines anyways. Most of this should go into the model.

Check this plugin or look at its code to get an idea. https://github.com/CakeDC/users/

Comment: Thanks burzum, i had a look at that plugin and it looks great. Most of my controller code (above) is the same as in that plugin.. and i have spent allot of time on it to just throw it away and use this plugin lol. I have updated the above with my beforeFilter's if it makes it any clearer... im stumped as to why the register form validates fine but not the login form. Also the model has the correct validation checks as the register form works..